# How do I recover files from a single degraded mdadm raid1 drive? "not enough to start the array"

Tags: data-recovery, software-raid, mdadm

Given a single raid1 drive in degraded/rebuilding state, can it be force mounted?  I'd like to recover all the files before undertaking the dangerous operation of pairing it and rebuilding.  As far as I can tell the drive is in perfectly good shape, fully intact. The pair drive is partly failed.

If the drive was not in rebuilding state I'd know exactly what to do. Here is what I have tried:

```
# mdadm --verbose --assemble /dev/md8 /dev/sdb1  --force
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md8
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is identified as a member of /dev/md8, slot 1.
mdadm: no uptodate device for slot 0 of /dev/md8
mdadm: added /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md8 as 1
mdadm: /dev/md8 assembled from 0 drives and  1 rebuilding - not enough to start the array.

# cat /proc/mdstat                       
md8 : inactive sdb1[1](S)
      976759808 blocks super 1.2          
md0 : active raid1 sdc1[0]
      976759672 blocks super 1.2 [2/1] [U_]

# mdadm --stop /dev/md8
mdadm: stopped /dev/md8

# mount /dev/sdb1 /mnt/temp2
mount: unknown filesystem type 'linux_raid_member'

# mount -o ro -t ext3 -b 2048 /dev/sdb1 /mnt/temp1
mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb1.

# foremost -i /dev/sdb -o /tmp/foo    (this results in perfectly good files)
```

In this particular case the `foremost` command recovers files, so something is definitely on the drive, if I could only get the superblock offset correct.

And in this particular case assembling both halves of the array crashes the kernel(!), so that's not a real option anyway (aside from the safety issues).

---

UPDATE: added output of mdadm

```
# mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1
/dev/sdb1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 1.2
    Feature Map : 0x2
     Array UUID : e00a291e:016bbe47:09526c90:3be48df3
           Name : ubuntu:0
  Creation Time : Wed May 11 12:26:39 2011
     Raid Level : raid1
   Raid Devices : 2

 Avail Dev Size : 1953519616 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
     Array Size : 1953519344 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
  Used Dev Size : 1953519344 (931.51 GiB 1000.20 GB)
    Data Offset : 2048 sectors
   Super Offset : 8 sectors
Recovery Offset : 0 sectors
          State : clean
    Device UUID : 41346f44:ccacbbf7:0c17c133:eb7b341f

    Update Time : Sat Apr 13 00:02:08 2013
       Checksum : 483a0a44 - correct
         Events : 402833


   Device Role : Active device 1
   Array State : AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing)
```

Comment: Output of `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1`?

Comment: Added to question.

Comment: `blockdev --getsize /dev/sdb1` is 1953521664 or larger? `cat /proc/mdstat` includes `Personalities : [raid1]`?

Comment: @frostschutz yes to both.

Comment: You appear to have both drives, so why are you trying to only use one of them?

Comment: Each is bad in its own way.  Between the two I hope to get everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If it's RAID 1, and if you know the data offset (e.g. 2048 sectors, you can usually find out the exact data offset by `mdadm --examine /dev/sdb1`), then you can create a read-only (to be safe) loop device like so:

```
# losetup --find --show --read-only --offset $((2048*512)) /dev/sdb1

/dev/loop7
```

And then try to check then mount the printed loop device:

```
# fsck.ext3 -n -v /dev/loop7
# mount -o ro /dev/loop7 /mnt/recovery
```

mount might be able do this directly with the `-o ro,loop,offset=` options, but I prefer to create the loop device manually, just to make sure it's really read-only.

If the filesystem itself is damaged, you should make an image using `dd`, and run experiments such as `fsck` on the image. Alternatively you can use Linux network block device to put a copy-on-write layer on top of the disk, so you can `fsck` that layer without actually writing anything onto the disk itself (`nbd-server -c`/`nbd-client`, will create a `/dev/nbdX` device for you to play with). It might be possible to do the same with device mapper - but I've never tried it.

Comment: "mount -o ro -t ext3 /dev/loop7 /mnt/temp1" gives "mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop7". A similar raid1 drive works with "mount -o ro -t ext3 -b 2048 /dev/sde1 /mnt/temp1".

Comment: What does `file -s` say for the created loop device?

Comment: "file -s" shows "Linux rev 1.0 ext3 filesystem data, UUID=ad88ff39-8f6c-4bb9-80de-bf56feae31b1 (needs journal recovery) (large files)".  See also   http://superuser.com/questions/256251/detect-filesystem-type-cant-mount-filesystem-image-img

Comment: So the loop device / offset should be good. Anything in dmesg when you try to mount? The filesystem may be damaged somehow.

Comment: yeah, looks like the drive is bad, though SMART self-check passes: "fsck.ext3: Attempt to read block from filesystem resulted in short read while trying to re-open /dev/loop1"

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I've just spent hours reading everything I could to mount my single-drive broken raid0 and this is the only thing that worked! I created a loop device using the data offset found by `mdadm --examine /dev/DRIVE`, and can now mount it. Thank you a thousand times!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set the number of raid devices in your array to one using:

```
mdadm /dev/md8 --grow --raid-devices=1 --force
```

After that look in `/proc/mdstat` to see if `md8` is active. You should probably mount it read-only until you have copied of the data.

Comment: # mdadm /dev/md8 --grow --raid-devices=1 --force gives "mdadm: /dev/md8 is not an active md array - aborting"

Comment: Have you tried `mdadm --assemble --scan` that might work because md8 shows up in the `/proc/mdstat`. You still have to mount md8 afterwards

Comment: I'd really prefer to just skip the raid complexity and just mount the underlying fs.

Comment: In that case you have to go with the offset. I tried recreating the error you get with a script, but even though I get the `no uptodate device for slot 1 of /dev/md8` the `/dev/md8` start (in degraded mode). I have had that both with just removing the other drive and with assigning the other one to /dev/md0. I did have to reboot the machine often, as somehow the kernel keeps information about the raid partitions even when a raid device is stopped and zero-ed. But even without rebooting I was never able to reproduce the problem.